# Typescript Angular ui bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am using angular.ui.bootstrap modal to show a form in a modal. Everything is working fine, except when I close the modal, I want a table on the parent page to be updated with the new item added in the modal.

My parent controller:

```
module MyApp.Controllers {

export interface IController {
    items: Models.IItem[];
}

export interface IControllerScope {

}

export class Controller implements IController {
    items: Models.IItem[];

    constructor(
        private $scope: IControllerScope,
        private $modal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) {

    }

    addItem() {
        var options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings = {
            templateUrl: '/directives/formFirective',
            controller: 'formController',
            controllerAs: 'modal',
            resolve: {
                id: () => 1234
            }
        };

        this.$modal.open(options).result
            .then(function (item) {
                // How do I add item to the instance variable items here?
                this.items.push(item) // Does not work here :(
                console.log(item)
            });
    }
}
```

}

Then in the formController I have:

```
this.$modalInstance.close(item);
```

My question is how to add the item to the instance variable items on the parent controller on modal close?

Thanks.

Comment: that looks correct. Maybe you need to add `items` to the $scope? Do you get a console.log from the `then`-function?

Comment: I fixed it by removing the function like this......then((item) => this.updateList(item))

Comment: Hi, Bill I have a very similar issue. I just wonder how do you access the Id 1234 that you are passing in the other controller. Can you please post your code including the template as a sample please?

Comment: Hi user1829319, You just inject it into the constructor, the same way you would inject anything. Like this 'constructor(
            private id: number,
            ) { }'

Answer (score 1):

try to change =>

```
function (item) {
                // How do I add item to the instance variable items here?
                this.items.push(item) // Does not work here :(
                console.log(item)
            }
```

in to:

```
(item) => {
                // How do I add item to the instance variable items here?
                this.items.push(item) // Does not work here :(
                console.log(item)
            }
```